# Order for "Bundle products" is not able to send for shipment (Stock Source does not have options)

Tags: shipping, order-status, bundled-product, inventory

First of all i searched a lot in other related issues, but does not found identical to my problem (apologies if i missed it).
#The problem

1. I have an order for Bundle products (3 separate ones combine together).
2. Anyone of those separate products have stock availability.
3. If any of them is ordered separately there's no issue to be shipped.

- the user was able to place successfully the order, but now I as an admin - not able to complete it.

As you can see at the images attached bellow (source for stock is missing in order) and the other image shows Bundle product details (all separate product have more stock than needed to execute the order). P.S - *real names of products and sources are changed - due it is public store and order..
[image: Not able to select source for bundle items]

[image: Bundle product details]